# How to apply Angular2 pipes to dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-pipe

I need to apply a Pipe (transformation) to format dynamic content provided via an API.  The data is actually being applied via a custom formatter that essentially binds to [innerHTML] on an element.  The problem is the pipe I append does not apply, as required.

For example,  I'm receiving the following value ***AB123456D*** (UK, National Insurance No) and I want to display it like so **AB 12 34 45 D**

Restrictions imposed upon me are that data is formatted and inserted to the template via bindings using [innerHTML].

```
// template
<span *ngSwitchWhen="'html'" [innerHTML]="display"></span>


// helper function
display(): string {
  ...
  return this.column.formatter.replace(/\{([^}]*)\}/g, (match, id) => _.get(this.data, id));
  ...
}

// formatter looks like this and my pipe's name is `ni`
<div>{niNum} | ni</div>
```

When rendered, I see the following...

```
AB123456D | ni
```

when I want / expect to see...

```
AB 12 34 45 D
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved, or whether it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't process content added by `[innerHtml]="..."` in any way. It's just passed to the browser as is.

Comment: Thanks.  Any ideas, approaches that will work?  I can make changes to the template implementation but not the formatter approach.

Comment: Prepare the HTML string imperatively before sending to `[innerHtml]="..."`. I don't know a better way.